# sbyte smallest signed byte?

Tags: assembly, x86

In the book assembly_language_for_x86_processors by kip irvine he writes

val4 SBYTE -128  ; smallest signed byte.
var3 SBYTE  127  ; largest signed byte.

I thought that the first bit is the sign bit.  So should the smallest byte not be -127?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably thinking of what's called sign/magnitude representation, where the sign bit just multiplies the rest by -1 or not.  One's complement, where the sign bit has a place-value of `-(2^(n-1) - 1)`, would also only range from `[-127 .. 127]`, but x86 and all other modern machines use 2's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way. In two's complement representation, the value of each bit is 2 to the power of its zero-based position, except for the sign bit, where it's negative.

Let's spell it out. Imagine you have an 8-bit number `abcdefgh`. Each letter `a..h` corresponds to a bit, its value can be either zero or one. The integer value of that bit sequence is:

```
(-128)a + 64b + 32c + 16d + 8e + 4f + 2g + h
```

So the smallest byte sized integer is the one that has 1 in the `a` position and zeros elsewhere. That's -128. And the largest one would be the one with 0 in the `a` position and 1's elsewhere. Count them, it's 127.

Answer (score 0):

In [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the range of an *n*-bit word is [-(2<sup>*n*  -1</sup>), 2<sup>*n* - 1</sup> - 1]. So, for an `sbyte`, which is 8 bits, it's [-128, 127].

For example, the minimum 8-bit signed value (`sbyte`) is 10000000 in binary. In two's complement, the representation of *x* is the representation of *-x* after flipping all the bits and adding one:

```
 10000000     =  x
 01111111 + 1 = -x
010000000     = -x = 128

            x = -128
```